# 2 = 1 Why are values I enter in Blender getting halved?

Tags: units

[image]

[image]

After I enter a value of '1', it gets divided by '2'. Why does this happen, and how do I get rid of it? This happens everywhere where I enter a value. Enter '4' it becomes '2', enter '16', it becomes '8'. Are one of my settings wrong or something?

Answer (score 5):

You must have accidentally set the Unit Scale property to 0.5. It can be found in the Scene tab, in the Properties Editor under Units. You should set it to 1.

[image]

Comment: Did Blender 2.80 fixed this problem? The parser now only accept the number as the unit you set

Comment: What problem? Accidentally setting things to wrong values? That is not fixed in 2.80 I'm afraid, you can still do that.

Comment: In my setting(2.80.64), I use `0.5` Unit Scale and set to *metric*. When I directly enter `1` in Transform panel, it set to `1m` and the actual value is `bpy.context.object.location[i] = 2`

Comment: That feature is an improvement in Blender's handling of units, it is not a solution to some problem and certainly not this one. One still needs to know what values they set and why if you ask me...

Comment: Thank you so much for answering the question.